# Speed up resampling from array

Tags: julia

I'm doing a lot of resampling from large arrays, by row, and I was wondering if there's a way to speed it up. For example

```
n = 10^4
a = rand(Float64, (n,n))
@time r = a[sample(1:n,n),:]
```

I usually get about 0.8 seconds on my machine. `sample()` itself is quite fast. Indeed, `r = a[1:n, :]` is just about as slow as the above. I know these are large arrays, but am I missing something obvious? An order of magnitude speedup would be wonderful...

EDIT: I have selected Przemyslaw Szufel's answer as it is nice and comprehensive, and definitely much faster if you're not going to further manipulate the array. Unfortunately in my case, Fredrik Bagge's caution proved true: it was not overall faster to use views, because subsequent operations to the array become slower--it was basically a wash in my testing. Also, Oscar Smith made a good point about column major. In my case, I later do something across the other dimension that's even more expensive the resampling so it made sense to leave the array as it is.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you can sample by columns instead, that will also probably help a lot, as Julia is column major.

Comment: This might not hold in your use case, but in some applications, permuting the array once and reusing it is feasible (e.g., SGD with minibatches).  This has the advantage that caching is not disturbed.

Comment: @phipsgabler I don't quite get what you mean? How would you permute it once?

Comment: With minibatches, you don't need to create them every time using `data[sample(1:N, B)]`, where `B` is the batch size. It is better to have `data = shuffle!(data)`, and then cycle through it with `data[1:B]`, `data[B+1:2B]`, etc. That way you don't get cache problems, since you  always access contiguously.

Comment: But `shuffle()` isn't resampling with replacement? (which is what I need to do). Although I do use `shuffle()` in a different context. Speaking of which, I don't understand the following. `x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]; shuffle!(x)` gives me a shuffled `x`. Now suppose I want to shuffle each column. `for j in 1:size(x,2); shuffle!(x[:,j]); end` does not change `x`, I have to say `x[:,j]=shuffle(x[:,j])` -- why is that?

Comment: It's not the same, no, that's why I just commented. For the other thing, that would make a separate question, but the reason is that indexing creates a copy. You can `shuffle!(view(x, :, j))`, though, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `view`s for a 2000x speedup!

```
julia> const n = 10^4; const a = rand(Float64, (n,n));

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime a[sample(1:n,n),:];
  336.622 ms (6 allocations: 763.02 MiB)

julia> @btime a[:, sample(1:n,n)];
  230.512 ms (6 allocations: 763.02 MiB)

julia> @btime view(a,sample(1:n,n),:);
  164.601 μs (5 allocations: 78.31 KiB)

julia> @btime view(a,:, sample(1:n,n));
  165.601 μs (5 allocations: 78.31 KiB)
```

Note that when creating the view column or row selection does not matter. It will matter however when the data is going to be read from the view.

#### EDIT

@Fredrik Bagge made a very important comment  that using later the `view` will be much slower. While naturally, when copying data happens there is cost to be incurred, there are the following issues to remember:

1. In practice very often not all elements of a `view` might be used in data processing - in all those cases one gets an immediate speedup.
2. The memory footprint of a `view` approach will be much lower.
3. One can always materialize the view. Of course if you materialize the view you need to incur the cost of copying the data in memory. However it will not be slower than materializing directly. Let's benchmark:

```
julia> @btime a[sample(1:n,n),:];
  351.572 ms (6 allocations: 763.02 MiB)

julia> const myview = view(a, sample(1:n,n), :);

julia> @btime collect(myview);
  297.866 ms (2 allocations: 762.94 MiB)
```

These are results from my machine. Actually, for row-oriented querying of a matrix, creating a view and materializing it later seems to be faster than materializing the `Array` up-front.

Let's have a look at the column oriented matrix:

```
julia> @btime a[:, sample(1:n,n)];
  255.276 ms (6 allocations: 763.02 MiB)

julia> const myview2 = view(a, :, sample(1:n,n));

julia> @btime collect(myview2);
  297.952 ms (2 allocations: 762.94 MiB)
```

At least on my machine materializing the view has the same speed regardless of using column or row major. So for the example presented in the question is it actually faster, while for the optimized column-oriented code it is slower. 
However note again point (1.) - not always all data is subsequently used.

EDIT 2: Additional explanation following the second comment by Frederik. Benchmarking the `collect` code we have skipped the call to `sample` when measuring the times. However, note that the time to run `sample` is orders of magnitude smaller than the variance of subsequent runs of `@btime` it does not affect the results.

Comment: This is not the whole story though and might be misleading. Creating the view is much faster, but subsequent use of the array might become slower since elements are shuffled in memory. Creating a slice makes sure that elements are stored contiguously.

Comment: @Fredrik Bagge I made an edit to address your comments along with performance tests. It clearly shows the `view` is in many cases a better option.

Comment: Note that you can't really draw accurate conclusions from your current benchmarks since `a` is a global variable that is not interpolated into the benchmark expression. You also need to take the time for the call to `sample` into account for both timings. When you time `collect`, you assume the `sample` is free.

Comment: @Fredrik In my example `a` is a `const` and hence type-stable - that is why I did not have to interpolate it - I always do it that way when I am too lazy to type the `$` character :-). Creating `sample` with `view` took time measured of micro-second while the `collect` is measured in milliseconds - hence it did not matter here and I wanted to have the code short. However, you are right that maybe I should have mentioned about it.

Comment: @FredrikBagge - I just noted that I forgot to put `const` in front of `myview` so I should update my post. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Slicing into an array always creates a copy of the data, so this can get quite expensive for large slices. In your case, it would probably make sense to use a view, which doesn't create a copy, but references the underlying data in `a` instead. You can create a view either with the `@view` macro as `r = @view a[sample(1:n, n), :]` or by using the `view` function directly: `r = view(a, sample(1:n, n), :)`.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Note that while creating the view is much faster, subsequent use of the array might become slower since elements are shuffled in memory. Creating a slice makes sure that elements are stored contiguously.